# Organising columns in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 2 sets of 92 columns. At the moment, all 92 columns are in one row. Is it possible to reogranise this such that the 92 columns are split into sets of 12, essentially having 8 sets of 12 data (one underneath the other). my code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

os.chdir('C:/Users/peaches9/Desktop/')

Result = []

def FID_extract(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]

    new_dfa = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:17]  
        new_dfa[colname] = selected_data
    #print new_dfa 
    #new_dfa.to_csv('FID_11169_Liquid.csv') 
    Result.append(new_dfa)


def TCD_extract(filepath):

    path_pattern = filepath
    files = glob.glob(path_pattern)
    dataframes = [pd.DataFrame.from_csv(f, index_col=None) for f in files]

    new_dfb = pd.DataFrame()

    for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
        colname = 'Run {}'.format(i+1)
        selected_data = df['Unnamed: 3'].ix[12:15]  
        new_dfb[colname] = selected_data
    #print new_dfb 
    #new_dfb.to_csv('TCD_11169_liquid.csv') 
    Result.append(new_dfb)


FID_extract('C:/Users/peaches9/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/FID_0*') #files directory

TCD_extract('C:/Users/peaches9/Desktop/Cryostat Verification/GC results/11169_Cryo_1bar/TCD_0*')

dfc = pd.concat(Result)
```

Out:

```
     Run 1.....   Run 95      Run 96  
12  5193791.85  5193915.21  5194343.34  
13  1460874.04  1460929.33  1461072.84  
14   192701.82   192729.55   192743.99  
15    156836.4   156876.97   156889.26  
16    98342.84     98346.7    98374.95  
17         NaN         NaN         NaN  
12     3982.69     3982.16     4017.66  
13  2913008.04  2913627.33   2914075.7  
14   226963.37    226956.1   227106.71  
15     25208.2    25173.89    25197.88
```

I want all 96 columns split into 8 X 12 columns all underneath each other. Many thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have managed to seperate the dataframes into sets of 8... but I can't get each dataframe to go beneath each other. They concat to the right, always!

```
dfc = pd.concat(Result)

df1 = dfc.ix[:,0:12]
df2 = dfc.ix[:,12:24]
df3 = dfc.ix[:,24:36]
df4 = dfc.ix[:,36:48]
df5 = dfc.ix[:,48:60]
df6 = dfc.ix[:,60:72]
df7 = dfc.ix[:,72:84]
df8 = dfc.ix[:,84:96]

pieces = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5,df6,df7,df8]

df_final = pd.concat([df1, df2], levels = 1, axis = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are trying to take your 96 columns, and create a single 2-dimensional DataFrame with 12 columns and 8 times as many rows, then you want:

```
df_final = pd.concat( pieces, axis=0, ignore_index=True )
```

If you are trying to make a 3-dimensional DataFrame, with your new dimension having 8 values, you aren't trying to make a DataFrame, but a [Panel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html#from-dict-of-dataframe-objects).

Comment: I want 8 rows of data each with the 12 sets of columns (run 1 to 12) ... So the first set of data will be runs 1 to 12 and beneath this there will be runs 13 -24... and so on. The above code does do this but the data is somewhat warped... with each set of runs not underneath each other.

Comment: I'm not understanding your problem. If the data is aligned along the wrong axis, change the `axis=X` parameter.. If you want the data to print to the console in a particular way, write a function that prints the data to console in the way you want. If you are trying to make a data structure with 8 arrays of shape `N_samples*N_columns = N_samples*12`, then you need to go to Panels, like I suggested.

Comment: problem was solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840128/how-to-stack-data-frames-on-top-of-each-other-in-pandas