# loop for computing average of selected data in dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a 3 row x 96 column dataframe. I'm trying to computer the average of the two rows beneath the index (row1:96) for every 12 data points. here is my dataframe:

```
 Run 1       Run 2      Run 3       Run 4       Run 5       Run 6  \
0  1461274.92  1458079.44  1456807.1  1459216.08  1458643.24  1457145.19   
1   478167.44   479528.72  480316.08   475569.52   472989.01   476054.89   
2      ------      ------     ------      ------      ------      ------   

    Run 7       Run 8       Run 9      Run 10     ...          Run 87  \
0  1458117.08  1455184.82  1455768.69  1454738.07     ...      1441822.45   
1   473630.89   476282.93   475530.87   474200.22     ...        468525.2   
2      ------      ------      ------      ------     ...          ------   

   Run 88      Run 89      Run 90      Run 91      Run 92      Run 93  \
0  1445339.53  1461050.97  1446849.43  1438870.43  1431275.76  1430781.28   
1    460076.8   473263.06   455885.07   475245.64   483875.35   487065.25   
2      ------      ------      ------      ------      ------      ------   

   Run 94      Run 95      Run 96  
0  1436007.32  1435238.23  1444300.51  
1   474328.87   475789.12   458681.11  
2      ------      ------      ------  

[3 rows x 96 columns]
```

Currently I am trying to use df.irow(0) to select all the data in row index 0.

something along the lines of:

```
selection = np.arange(0,13)

for i in selection:
    new_df = pd.DataFrame()
    data = df.irow(0)

    ........
```

then i get lost

I just don't know how to link this range with the dataframe in order to computer the mean for every 12 data points in each column.

To summarize, I want the average for every 12 runs in each column. So, i should end up with a separate dataframe with 2 * 8 average values (96/12). 
any ideas?

thanks.

Comment: Your question is a little confusing - it says your data has 3 rows and 96 columns, but then talks about rows[1:96] .  Can you give some example output?  Is it related to [your earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30840128/how-to-stack-data-frames-on-top-of-each-other-in-pandas)?  Do you mean you want to average every set of 12 ***columns***?  If so - iiuc - you want a df with the average for each row per group of 12?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a groupby on axis=1 (using some dummy data I made up):

```
>>> h = df.iloc[:2].astype(float)
>>> h.groupby(np.arange(len(h.columns))//12, axis=1).mean()
          0         1         2         3         4         5         6         7
0  0.609643  0.452047  0.536786  0.377845  0.544321  0.214615  0.541185  0.544462
1  0.382945  0.596034  0.659157  0.437576  0.490161  0.435382  0.476376  0.423039
```

---

First we extract the data and force recognition of a float (the presence of the `------` row means that you've probably got an `object` dtype, which will make the `mean` unhappy.)

Then we make an array saying what groups we want to put the different columns in:

```
>>> np.arange(len(df.columns))//12
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
       3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
       5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
       7, 7, 7, 7], dtype=int32)
```

which we feed as an argument to `groupby`.  `.mean()` handles the rest.

Comment: This makes sense but for some reason it's not allowing me to group by any axis. =/

Comment: @Joey: unfortunately "it's not allowing me" doesn't really give me any information to help figure out what the problem is.

Comment: It worked fine. I was making a rookie error. Many thanks for this, it really helped to condense my code. :)

Answer (score 1):

It's always best to try to use `pandas` methods when you can, rather than iterating over the rows. The DataFrame's `iloc` method is useful for extracting any number of rows.

The following example shows you how to do what you want in a two-column DataFrame. The same technique will work independent of the number of columns:

```
In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [1, 2, "-"], "y": [3, 4, "-"]})

In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   x  y
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  -  -

In [16]: df.iloc[2] = df.iloc[0:2].sum()

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   x  y
0  1  3
1  2  4
2  3  7
```

However, in your case you want to sum each group of eight cells in df.iloc[2]`, so you might be better simply taking the result of the summing expression with the statement

```
ds = df.iloc[0:2].sum()
```

which with your data will have the form

```
col1    0
col2    1
col3    2
col4    3
   ...
col93  92
col94  93
col95  94
col96  95
```

(These numbers are representative, you will obviously see your column sums). You can then turn this into a 12x8 matrix with

```
ds.values.reshape(12, 8)
```

whose value is

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7],
   [ 8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
   [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31],
   [32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39],
   [40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
   [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55],
   [56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63],
   [64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71],
   [72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79],
   [80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87],
   [88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95]])
```

but summing this array will give you the sum of all elements, so instead create another DataFrame with

```
rs = pd.DataFrame(ds.values.reshape(12, 8))
```

and then sum that:

```
rs.sum()
```

giving

```
0    528
1    540
2    552
3    564
4    576
5    588
6    600
7    612
dtype: int64
```

You may find in practice that it is easier to simply create two 12x8 matrices in the first place, which you can add together before creating a dataframe which you can then sum. Much depends on how you are reading your data.